# Dynamically generate Input Fields and insert field data into seperate rows in a table

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have some form code that creates the form controls dynamically. I need to insert each dynamically generated form field into a separate table row: For example, if 5 questions are derived for a form, the user will enter the answer, the questionid and answer needs to be inserted into table Questions: questionID, answers.

How do I loop over `FORM` to acquire the result? This is what I tried:

```
<cfform name="form" method="post" action="TestQA.cfm">
  <table border="0">
   <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>question</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <cfoutput query="rsQuestions">
     <tr>
       <td><cfinput type="hidden" name="question_id" 
               id="question_id" 
               value="#rsQuestions.question_id#">
       </td>
       <td>#rsQuestions.question#</td>
       <td>
            <cfif #rsQuestions.question_type_id# eq 1>
                <cfinput type="text" name="answer" 
                        message="#rsQuestions.Message#" 
                        tooltip="#rsQuestions.Tooltip#" 
                        range="#rsQuestions.range#"   
                        required="Yes" 
                        size="#rsQuestions.Size#" 
                        method="Post">
            </cfif>
       </td>
     </tr>  
     </cfoutput>
     <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td><cfinput type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
</cfform>
```

The procedure to insert the questions into table:

```
<cfloop collection=#form# item="field"> 
    <cfif field neq 'submit'>
        <cfquery datasource="dstest">  
            INSERT INTO dbo.group_member_questionnaire_answers (question_id, answer)
            VALUES(#form.Question_ID#, #form.Answer#)
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>Answers inserted successfully into database</cfoutput>
```

I have adjusted statement to this:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#val(form.TotalFields)#" index="x"> 

        <cfquery datasource="dsED">  
        INSERT INTO dbo.group_member_questionnaire_answers (question_id, answer)
        VALUES(#form.Question_ID#, #form.Answer#)
        </cfquery>



</cfloop>

This is the result: Error Executing Database Query.  
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Invalid column name 'no'.

The error occurred in

7 :         <cfquery datasource="dstest">  
8 :         INSERT INTO dbo.group_member_questionnaire_answers (question_id, answer)
9 :         VALUES(#form.Question_ID#, #form.Answer#)
10 :         </cfquery>
11 :         
________________________________________
SQL    INSERT INTO dbo.group_member_questionnaire_answers (question_id, answer) VALUES(62,63, 90,no)
DATASOURCE    dsED
VENDORERRORCODE   207
SQLSTATE      42S22

Resources:
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Some ColdFusion / HTML / SQL might give us something to work with here

Comment: The following code tries to insert into one record:

Comment: that depends on the form. For example are you getting a LIST of question IDS in your form.question_ID? (as in 134,1343,203)  Or perhaps you have form elements like Form.question_#questionID# ... there are 12 ways to do this. It's not obvious what you are trying to do from the information given. sorry.

Comment: Johan - This is a very common task. Take a look at the archives first. There are a bunch threads that describes different options for handling this scenario, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857537/creating-a-dynamic-form-but-how-to-do-the-query). Have a try at adapting it and post back if you have problems.

Comment: Hi Leigh, I have adjusted statement to this:

Comment: You may want to re-read the other thread again. Processing multiple form fields involves more than just adding a "total" field. The form field *names* must be made unique. One way of doing that is to add a counter number, so the names are sequential `question_1|answer_1,question_2,answer_2, ...`.  That is where the "total" field comes in. It used in a `from/to` loop to generate a counter number. The counter number is used *within* the loop to extract the form field values using associative array notation: ie `<cfset questionID = FORM["question_"& counter]>`.

Comment: Like I mentioned, there are different ways to handle it, but ultimately they all involve unique field names. Here is [a fuller example of the counter number approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518802/coldfusion-update-array-using-cfform-change-values-after-submit/18523123#18523123).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using the same ID for each question/answer input field.  So at best you'll end up with a list like:

```
question_id = 1,2,3,4,5
answer = foo,foo,foo,foo,bar
```

Instead a better approach is to give each answer its own id, based on the question ID.  You can then loop over these quite easily in the form handler.

This isn't a particularly sophisticated approach, but should give you the basic idea:

```
   <!--- 1 hidden field with all the IDs --->
   <cfoutput><input type="hidden" name="question_ids" id="question_ids" value="#valueList(rsQuestions.question_id)#"></cfoutput>
   <cfoutput query="rsQuestions">
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>#rsQuestions.question#</td>
       <td>
            <cfif rsQuestions.question_type_id eq 1>
                <cfinput type="text" name="answer_#rsQuestions.question_id#" 
                        message="#rsQuestions.Message#" 
                        tooltip="#rsQuestions.Tooltip#" 
                        range="#rsQuestions.range#"   
                        required="Yes" 
                        size="#rsQuestions.Size#">
            </cfif>
       </td>
     </tr>  
     </cfoutput>
```

Then loop over that hidden form, inserting the question/answer for each:

```
<cfloop list="#form.question_ids#" index="question"> 
        <cfquery datasource="dstest">  
            INSERT INTO dbo.group_member_questionnaire_answers (question_id, answer)
            VALUES(<cfqueryparam value="#question#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">, <cfqueryparam value="#form['answer_' & question]#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">)
        </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

PS: you usually don't need the # # in  tags, i.e. `<cfif #rsQuestions.question_type_id# eq 1>` can be written as `<cfif rsQuestions.question_type_id eq 1>`

And there is no `method` attribute on the cfinput tag.

Comment: Yes, that is another way to approach it. A couple improvements though: if you prefer using a list of numeric id's, you do not need `valueList`. Just put that field inside the loop, and all of the id's will be submitted as a comma delimited list. Do not forget to use `cfqueryparam` (for both performance and sql injection protection). Also, the loop should be wrapped in a `cftransaction` to ensure data integrity.

Comment: Thank you Duncan! This works perfectly. Appreciate your input Leigh.

Comment: @Johan - Be sure to use cfqueryparam in your actual code - on all user supplied query parameters. Otherwise you are just asking to be hacked. (There are other reasons to use it as well, but that is the most important in a web app).